# How to get all unique words from numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following ndarray: X_train: [[<'title'>, <'description'>]]

```
array([['Boots new', 'Boots 46 size new'], ['iPhone 7 plus 128GB Red',
        '\xa0/\n/\n The price is only for Instagram subscribers'], ...],
      dtype=object)
```

I want to get a list of all unique words. 
How can I do it the fastest way?
Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: I think np.unique https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html you are looking for

Comment: I'm not sure how I can implement it in my situation. Should I create a new array with all the words?

Comment: You would need to look for vectorizing it. preprocessing involving -- stop-word removal, tokenization, other removals based on data etc.. then you would create a bag-of-words or tfidf?

Comment: I actually need to process BOW without vectorizing. So the first step is to get unique words from ndarray. I cannot figure out how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you care about words in the title and the description so this takes from both but can be modified easily.

If you want to track unique things a set is usually a good type to use since it won't let you add multiple of the same element.

This code will build up the set of unique words in all the titles and descriptions. I added the ignore list in case there are special words you want ignored. This could be made more sophisticated with regular expressions if needed.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([['Boots new', 'Boots 46 size new'], ['iPhone 7 plus 128GB Red',
                '\xa0/\n/\n The price is only for Instagram subscribers']],
                dtype=object)

words = set()
ignore = ["/", "7"]
for title, description in arr:
    words.update(set(word for word in title.strip().split() if word not in ignore))
    words.update(set(word for word in description.strip().split() if word not in ignore))

print(words)
```

This prints

```
{'price', 'Boots', 'subscribers', 'size', '46', 'Instagram', '128GB', 'new', 'plus', 'iPhone', 'is', 'only', 'for', 'The', 'Red'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your examples as the data. But this code will work regardless of your array dimensions.

```
data = np.array([['Boots new', 'Boots 46 size new'], 
                 ['iPhone 7 plus 128GB Red','\xa0/\n/\n The price is only for Instagram subscribers']])
split_data = np.char.split(data, sep =' ') 
all_words = np.sum(split_data)
unique_words = np.unique(all_words)
```

`split_data` stores the words in lists, so a simple list summation would give you all words. Later on you can use `np.unique` function.

Comment: Cannot get why the split gives me a mistake: string operation on non-string array .

Comment: It is related to `dtype=object` part. I don't why you need to use an `object` array, but you can add `.astype(np.str)` at the end of array definition and then the function will get its desired input.

Comment: And also a comment that I cannot post under @ryanh153 's post because of my reputation, using this '`title` and `description` fixed' approach is not the best way if your arrays can dynamically change in time - they assume this array with fixed rules, not generalizable. Also, using loops with numpy arrays are strongly discouraged due to time concerns. If the input array size becomes huge, using loops would be so time consuming.

Comment: If you don't want the array to change at all, you can use ```split_data = np.char.split(data.astype(np.str), sep =' ') ``` too.